# lambda inline editor alternative

Tags: lambda, editor, inline

I'm using windows 10 system.
I have a raspberry Pi3 and I use it only as IoT.
I have implemented a lambda function that use "aws-iot-device-sdk". It use the MQTT method. 
I use the inline editor ,all  amazon pages web site etc etc etc , on my windows 10 machine.
I have used the Raspbian machine like a unix machine ONLY for certs process and for the "aws-iot-device-sdk" and for zip the file to be send to the lambda aws console.
All works perfectly.
Now I have seen that if I need to be more "interactive" with alexa I must use the alexa-sdk. (Questions from alexa, answers, then questions ..and so on...)
On my raspberry I have downloaded it . Added it to my zip file that now contains :

1) index.js
2) "node-modules" folder with "Alexa-sdk" and "aws-iot-device-sdk"
3) certs folder necessary for MQTT

Everything hasn't changed except that i added the "alexa-sdk" folder.

After having sent the zip file to my lambda function, go back to my windows 10 workstation ,i see that i cannot edit my function anymore because it load 6,2 Mb.
I'm desperated. !!!!!
It is impossible for me to edit a line ore two, (because i am not expert and i must try an study what i am doing), zip everything, send the zip file, go back to windows , and test if it works. 
If I mistake something like a ";" ,or some more ………….. have to go back to unix machine, edit the code, re-zip ...etc etc , re-send , go back to windows and cross-the-finger...…..
It's impossible. !!!!!!!!!! 
How can i have my editor inline back ?

Or there is an alternative solutions that give me the possibility to have on online editor that make me save and test ?

I'm completely new about this. 
Is there a way to let me write / modify code of my lambda function and TEST on my pc quickly ?

Thanks a lot to all

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, yes thats how you have to do it.  You do lose access to the inline editor, but it's not that bad.  I follow the same workflow and here is what 
I use:
 1. Atom.IO to do my editing.  It's a great editor that you can customize to your needs.

2. Create a shell script that facilitates the upload of your script.  If you haven't already you will need to install & configure the AWS CLI. More information here: [Download & Install AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html)
3. On your Pi inside the root folder of your project create a shell script called lambda_upload.sh or similar containing the following:

   rm lambda.zip

   cd lambda

   chmod -R 777 *

   npm install

   zip -r ../lambda.zip *

   cd ..

   /home/"YourUserName"/.local/bin/aws lambda update-function-code --function-name "LambdaFunctionName" --zip-file fileb://lambda.zip
4. Then once you have applied changes to your code, save the file, update git if you're using it, then run the script to upload.

** Credit to acloud.guru which is where I learned this technique.  It's really helpful.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Put returns in code.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. I'll try and let you know.